# Open Source Projects to practice TDD/BDD in C#

Tags: open-source, tdd, bdd, testdriven.net

Can someone name some sample open source projects (C#) that would help me to put TDD,DDD concepts in to practice. (Beginner to Intermediate level)
I have a good understanding of the concepts, but never used them in a proper project.

I prefer if it was a C# server side development project ( class libraries, web servies, WCF etc) rather than a UI project; so that I could focus my attention into TDD,DDD side of it only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `NerdDinner` and `CodeCampServer` have both extensive unit tests, and are developed in TDD fashion, but it was really a long time from my last check on these projects...

TDD is generally really easy using right patterns for right things, when you follow SOLID principles and DI / IoC concepts to make your classes testable (and most important, sort of MVC for the presentation where usually most of your tests lie).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response which is helpful.<br> I'd prefer if it was a server side project, as that would let me focus on the core TDD/DDD aspects and not be worried about UI.

Comment: NerdDinner - no unit tests or any tests there

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It combines TDD, BDD, and a little DDD

UBADDAS - User Behaviour and Domain Driven Acceptance Stories

found here - http://kernowcode.github.io/UBADDAS/

It produces console output like this

```
I want to register a new user 
  So that Increase customer base
       As user
    Given Register customer
     When Confirm customer registration
     Then Login customer
```